# VBA Find and Replace Text in a Text File

Tags: vba, excel

I need to modify a text file with strings in a specific column in excel. When I execute the code I find some values are duplicated. It seems to be related to the old value end numeric which somehow is interpreted as a copy. However, this doesn't occur every time and I'm stumped. There are 10,000 entries to change but the small test file I've created reveals a larger problem. 
[Test Files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13CHlgolVrz2W1BowzzKkBfgptyqdBTtu) Hopefully this link works properly, if it does you will find Test.txt my test file, TestBook.xlsm and Test - L5K.txt which contains a portion of the actual file to be modified.

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim sBuffer As String, sSubstitute As String, sFileName 
As String, sNewTagRef As Variant
Dim sOldFileRef As Variant
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer, iFileNum As Integer

'Path to target file
sFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

' Find the last row of specified column
Lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Lastrow

        'sOldFileRef is the search value and sNewTagRef is replacement value
        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        sOldFileRef = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
        sNewTagRef = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value

          'Prepare file text for replacement text
          Do While Not EOF(iFileNum)
              Line Input #iFileNum, sBuffer
              sSubstitute = sSubstitute & sBuffer & vbNewLine

          Loop

      Close iFileNum

     'Search and Replace text
     sSubstitute = Replace(sSubstitute, sOldFileRef, sNewTagRef)

     'Modify text file
     iFileNum = FreeFile
     Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
     Print #iFileNum, sSubstitute

Next i

Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: You have your order of events mixed up I think. I would **1** Open file for input **2** Open a second file for output  **3** for each input line, use a vlookup to find if there's a substituted value **4** Write out the original or substituted value to the output file.  **5** close both files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: reworked asfter looking at your source files - I had made some wrong assumptions about those...

**NOTE:** some of your search terms are substrings of other search terms, so you will need to sort the mapping table in order of descending term length, or you'll end up replacing the shorter part of a longer term.

Eg:

```
N21:370/08  Prep_Peel_Peeler1DisconnectSwitchAlarm
N21:370/02  Prep_Peel_Peeler2DisconnectSwitchAlarm
N21:370/0   Prep_Peel_HalvingUnitMotorDisconnectAlarm
```

if you replace N21:370/0 before the other two that will not give you the desired results.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    Dim sBuffer As String, sFileName As String
    Dim sFileNameOut As String
    Dim rngLookup As Range, m
    Dim iFileNumIn As Integer, iFileNumOut As Integer
    Dim arrMap, i As Long, numReplacements As Long

    'sFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename() 'Path to target file
    sFileName = "C:\_Stuff\test\Test - L5K.txt"

    iFileNumIn = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Input As iFileNumIn

    sFileNameOut = Replace(sFileName, ".txt", "_mod.txt")
    iFileNumOut = FreeFile
    Open sFileNameOut For Output As iFileNumOut

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngLookup = .Range(.Range("D2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
        arrMap = rngLookup.Value
    End With

    'Perform replacements
    Do While Not EOF(iFileNumIn)
        Line Input #iFileNumIn, sBuffer
        If Len(sBuffer) > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To UBound(arrMap)
                If InStr(sBuffer, arrMap(i, 1)) > 0 Then
                    sBuffer = Replace(sBuffer, arrMap(i, 1), arrMap(i, 2))
                    If numReplacements <= 10 Then Debug.Print arrMap(i, 1), ">>", arrMap(i, 2)
                    numReplacements = numReplacements + 1
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        Print #iFileNumOut, sBuffer
    Loop

    Close iFileNumIn
    Close iFileNumOut

    Debug.Print "Made " & numReplacements & " replacements"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tim, this works great on the mini test file and the full test file, however bombs on the real file. 

Here's an example of the real file;
    N: AFI()XIC(N21:536/0)ONS(B3/129)OTL(N120:511/0);
    N: [MOV(N120:511,N120:513) ,MOV(F418:182,F418:192) ,MOV(F418:183,F418:188) ,MOV(N101:289,F418:189) ,MOV(0.0,F418:190) ];
    N: [XIC(PD410:6/OLL) OTE(N120:514/4) ,XIC(PD410:6/OLH) OTE(N120:514/5) ,XIC(N120:513/0) XIO(N120:513/1) OTE(N120:514/0) ,XIO(N120:513/0) XIO(N120:513/1) OTE(N120:514/1) ,XIC(N120:513/1) OTE(N120:514/3) ];

Any ideas?

Comment: "bombs" - does it literally explode

Comment: What is different about the real file vs the test files?

Comment: Yep set the sprinklers off. As far as differences between two files formatting, test files are only a single column list of values. Where the actual file format is as you see above.

Comment: Presumably it didn't *actually* set the sprinklers off, so what *did* it do?  Is your real file much larger than the test files?

Comment: In the Test Files link posted above is a sample of the actual file.

Comment: No, it didn't set the sprinklers off. Though it didn't replace any of the values, granted in the sample provided and the small subset of value to swap there are only a few that would get changed. I can send a larger selection of replacement value if it helps. Yes, the real file will be much much larger.

Comment: Hey Tim, still having issues though not like they were. However, it does appear it is the 8 plus character in the old reference that is tacked on the end of the new value causing the duplication. Any ideas on what might cause that?

Fryer2_Fryer_FryerHoodliftDownStart88
Fryer2_Fryer_FryerHoodliftDownStart7
Fryer2_Fryer_FryerHoodliftDownStart6
Fryer2_Fryer_FryerHoodliftDownStart5
Fryer2_Fryer_FryerHoodliftDownStart4
Fryer2_Fryer_FryerHoodliftDownStart3
Fryer2_Fryer_FryerHoodliftDownStart2
O:022
Fryer2_Fryer_FryerHoodliftDownStart0
O:022/9
O:022/8
O:022/7
O:022/6
O:022/5
O:022/4

Comment: I can't make anything out of what you put in comments - if you want to post a sample input file which shows the problem and describe exactly where the problem is I will take a look.

Comment: Hi Tim last comment, your solution works. There is a caveat and has to do what you alluded to earlier. After creating all of the replacement tag names I look at the length of the old valve and sort in descending order all based solely on length. Thank you.